# Run tomcat project without pom.xml (like yum or apt-get)

Tags: maven

For a presentation purpose and installation handbook i like to run a tomcat-project directly with only maven installed.

I googled around an found:

1. a way to download the dependency directly my `mvn dependency:get`
2. a way to start the war by `mvn tomcat7:run`

Is there any way to have a short shell-command who download the dependency from the server, compile and start it?

Actually i got this:

```
mvn dependency:get tomcat7:run
  -DgroupId=XXXXX 
  -DartifactId=hasty-tumbleweed 
  -Dversion=0.9.2-SNAPSHOT 
  -DrepoUrl=file://C:/Users/woodcraft.xenther-vladic/.m2/repository
```

But `mvn` still try to find the plugin from the official maven repository.

Any Idea?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Of course you need to download the plugins and dependencies at least once to your local repo. After you did this once do you want to prohibit further internet access by Maven? Run it offline with the `-o` switch. Your title suggest you don't have a `pom.xml` for the project? You need to create at least a basic one to use Maven.

Comment: A maven project is `pom.xml`+`concrete project` right? And a compiled project is a `.jar` without a `pom.xml`. See the `hasty-tumbleweed` is a `hasty-tumbleweed.jar` and I think that its doesnt matter if the `hasty-tumbleweed.jar` has ever been the result of a maven-project. Maybe the source-project was a maven project but actually there is no `pom.xml` (whereat the use of `dependency:get` require at least the existence of a `maven-metadata.xml`)

Comment: I actually found the cool `tomcat7:exec-war` command.

Comment: @Peter When you find a solution to your own question, you should post it as answer. [Answering your own questions is explicitly allowed on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: `tomcat7:exec-war` is no answer, its just cool. It does not download and start a tomcat!

Answer (score 1):

Are you maybe missing [this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html):

> Caveat: will always check the central repository defined in the super pom

---

From the little information here, you make it look as if you're distributing files already (the repository stuff) so why not provide a POM as well, opening you up to doing whatever nifty Maven stuff you desire. Then you can do:

```
mvn install -f <path to your POM>
```

Comment: Its a good approach. But -f requires a local file, i'd like to use a url(have edited the heading of the Question).

Comment: See, i have no pom. so i have no `<path to your POM>`.

Comment: Yes, I got that you're trying to avoid a POM. But then it looked to me as if you were in fact distributing a local repository to point to, so I figured that you could easily enough deliver a POM along with that. How much easier is `mvn install -f ...` than the longer command-line only version that you'll end up with (if it ever works). People are going to be very challenged spelling it out all correctly. But I primarily aimed at answering your "Any Idea?" question. The rest is just philosophizing about how it could be :)